# Make for loop execute parallely with Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

Please convert below code to execute parallel, Here I'm trying to map nested dictionary with pandas column values. The below code works perfectly but consumes lot of time. Hence looking to parallelize the for loop(Note: `df.replace(Source_Dictionary)` also did the job but takes triple the time of below code).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':['bab'],'two':['abb'],'three':['bb']})
Source_Dictionary = {'one':{'dadd':1,'bab':1.5},
                    'two':{'ab':2},
                    'three':{'cc':1,'bb':3}}
required_columns = ['one','two','three']
def Feature_Map(x):
    df[x] = df[x].map(Source_Dictionary[x]).fillna(0)

for i in required_columns:
    Feature_Map(i)
print(df)
   one  two  three
0  1.5  0.0      3
```

Answer (score 0):

To speed up your execution you can use multi processing. Number of processes and its performance depends on the resource provided. Let's suppose you can afford 4 processes to be running in parallel.

Your function:

```
def Feature_Map(x):
df[x] = df[x].map(Source_Dictionary[x]).fillna(0)
```

Multi processing:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
for i in required_columns:
    pool.apply_async(Feature_Map, (i))
```

You can also implement code for waiting till the process has finished execution before exiting.

You can refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html for detailed usage.

Comment: When executed your above code. It didn't give me any result. Can you please check and let me know?

Comment: This is for running you loop with multiple processes. You need to do a `wait` and `get` in order to wait for processes to  finish and fetch the return of the function.

Comment: Please go through this specific section of working with multiple pools once - <https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers>

Comment: My problem is, I have 300 columns and just one value. currently its taking around 1sec to execute wanted to cut short to less than half second. But wait and get won't solve my problem here.

Answer (score -1):

have your tried the modin package?

Step1:
pip install modin

Step2:
replace 'import pandas as pd' with 'import modin.pandas as pd'

then enjoy it!