# Parallel Processing of Loop of Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I have the following code which I would like to speed up.

EDIT: we would like the columns in 'colsi' to be shifted by the group columns in 'colsj'. Pandas allows us to shift multiple columns at once through vectorization of 'colsi'. I loop through each group column and perform the vectorized shifts. Then I fill the NAs by the medians of the columns in 'colsi'. The reindex is just to create new blank columns before they are assigned. The issue is that I have many groups and looping through each is becoming time consuming.

EDIT2: My goal is to engineer new columns by the lag of each group. I have many group columns and many columns to be shifted. 'colsi' contains the columns to be shifted. 'colsj' contains the group columns. I am able to vectorize 'colsi', but looping through each group column in 'colsj' is still time consuming.

```
colsi = ['a', 'b', 'c']
colsj = ['d', 'e', 'f']
med = df[colsi].median()

for j in colsj:
    newcols=[j+i+'_n' for i in colsi]
    newmed = med.copy()
    newmed.index=newcols
    df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist()+newcols) 
    df[newcols] = df.groupby(j)[colsi].shift()
    df[newcols] = df[newcols].fillna(newmed)
```

Parallelization seems to be a good way to do it. Leaning on [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829286/make-for-loop-execute-parallely-with-pandas-columns), I attempted the following but it didn't work:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=3)

colsi = ['a', 'b', 'c']
colsj = ['d', 'e', 'f']
med = df[colsi].median()

def funct(j):
    newcols=[j+i+'_n' for i in colsi]
    newmed = med.copy()
    newmed.index=newcols
    df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist()+newcols) 
    df[newcols] = df.groupby(j)[colsi].shift()
    df[newcols] = df[newcols].fillna(newmed)

for j in colsj:
    pool.apply_async(funct, (j))
```

I do not have any knowledge on how to go about parallel processing, so I am not sure whats missing here. Please advise.

Comment: start by explaining your code please

Comment: Why do you have two lists with the same name

Comment: u may wanna look into pysparks, they will auto parallel ur code for u. similar to pandas

Comment: pandas works only on single core.Multiprocessing might not help.Check more online about this.

Comment: @cs95, I have explained more above. Hope this helps